# Use git with second compiled ssh

Tags: linux, git, ssh

My machine is on CentOS 5 and I can't upgrade it.

```
# ssh -V
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
# which ssh
/usr/bin/ssh
```

OpenSSH/OpenSSL are too old to connect to `ssh://git@altssh.bitbucket.org:443` (yes there is a proxy)

So I compiled a recent version of ssh and ssl in /tmp/ssh

```
# /tmp/ssh/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.9p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
```

It works like charme

```
# /tmp/ssh/bin/ssh -v git@altssh.bitbucket.org -p 443
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to altssh.bitbucket.org (via proxy).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as *********.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to altssh.bitbucket.org closed.
Transferred: sent 3552, received 1744 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9724.6, received 4774.7
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Now, how can I tell git to use /tmp/ssh/bin/ssh instead of /usr/bin/ssh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either prepend to `PATH` the base directory of the alternative `ssh` binary, or set the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to the path of the alternative `ssh`. For example:

```
export GIT_SSH=/to/ssh/bin/ssh
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thanks.